# Determining average values in single flowline using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, line, flow

I need to get the average (Velocity) values of 1000 points on my long flowline. I tried to make parallel lines on each gridpoint using the "copy Parallel" function. But there two problems. It takes too much time, and at the end I can't automatically construct points for all the perpendicular lines to the flowline. I need to do one by one.

How can I automatically construct points for all the lines? Or is there any other technique that I could apply (create a grid and later to create my flowline?)

#### Details

The flowline is 100km and has 1000 points. On each of them I need to have the width-average value. The width is 5km. In the center, where is the flowline, I have high Velocity values. Near to the sides the Velocity decreasing. I need to have the average value on each point from side to side. So, I create a "5km" line applied on each point perpendicular to the flowline. I found a way with a tool to construct points on each of 1000 small ("5km") lines. But, this takes too much time, and I need to have curves not only lines.

Comment: I find you question confusing, can you upload an image to help explain your text? You talking about sampling along your flowline a thousand points, you make reference to grid points then you start talking about parallel lines and constructing perpendiculars?

Comment: The flowline is 100km and has 1000 points. On each of them I need to have the width-average value. The width is 5km. In the center, where is the flowline, I have high Velocity values. Near to the sides the Velocity decreasing. I need to have the average value on each point from side to side. So, I create a "5km" line applied on each point perpendicular to the flowline. I found a way with a tool to construct points on each of 1000 small ("5km") lines. But, this takes too much time, and I need to have curves not only lines.